# Is it possible to make a typesafe function taking an array of a union type and returning an array of only one of the types in the union?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to make a typesafe function taking an array of a union type and returning an array of only one of the types in the union?

Something like `getOnlyBooksOrOnlyRocks` below (which is not correct TS syntax).

```js
  interface Book {
    age: number;
    pages: number;
  }

  interface Rock {
    age: number;
    shape: string;
  }

  type BookOrRock = (Book & { shape?: never }) | (Rock & { pages?: never });

  const isBook = (x: BookOrRock): x is Book => 'pages' in x;

  const getOnlyBooksOrOnlyRocks = <T extends BookOrRock>(array: BookOrRock[]) => {
    const filtered = [] as T[];

    for (const el of array) {
      if (T extends Book && isBook(el)) filtered.push(el);
      else if (T extends Rock && !isBook(el)) filtered.push(el);
    }

    return filtered;
  };

  const booksAndRocks: BookOrRock[] = [
    { age: 1, pages: 100 },
    { age: 1e9, shape: 'round' },
  ];

  const rocks = getOnlyBooksOrOnlyRocks<Rock>(booksAndRocks);
```

I would expect the variable `rocks` to be inferred as a `Rock[]`.

Comment: Can I ask why you're not using regular `filter`? See [this playground](https://tsplay.dev/mq37rw) - the type of `rocks` is inferred correctly.

Comment: @caTS I have a big object with nested objects that are either of type `A` or `B`. I made a generic function that recursively loops in the object and maps it to an array of some other type, and also accepts a filter function to leave some of the nested object out of the map. I would like to call this function with a map callback of `(x) => x as T` and a filter callback of `(x) => ('pages' in T ? x.pages === pages : false)`. I could use the function to get a map with all the elements and then use the regular `filter` to remove the unwanted ones, but I am still learning TS ...

Comment: ... and I am obsessed with these problems I don't know how to solve. Oftentimes after solving them I just throw away the solution cause I don't really need it, but still I need to understand the difference between TS limitations and my limitations.

Comment: So have you "oversimplified" the problem here? Can you edit the question to demonstrate what specific issue you are facing with your code? Also, note that you cannot access whatever generic type was given at runtime... so the API you have currently listed here (`getOnlyBooksOrOnlyRocks<Rock>(booksAndRocks)`) is not possible.

Comment: @caTS I could write an example closer to my actual use case, but I think that having a control flow that depends on the type that T gets at runtime is necessary for what I want to achieve.

Comment: @opensorcio TS types have no runtime (unless you use codegen), so you have to pass some argument to define `getOnlyBooksOrOnlyRocks` generic type

Comment: The only way this would work is to pass some *value* whose type determines `T`. (You're aware that TS types are erased upon transpilation to JS and therefore don't exist at runtime, right?) You need something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2zYrw) or [this](https://tsplay.dev/NB5Exw), for example.  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls ping via @jcalz to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz I tried the logic of the first playground you gave and in my use case it correctly narrows T. I am going for this approach. You can write an answer if you want. Thank you very much!

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with something like `getOnlyBooksOrOnlyRocks<Rock>(booksAndRocks)` is that TypeScript's static type system, which includes [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type arguments like `<Rock>`,  is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) when the code is transpiled into JavaScript.  So the actual code that runs would look like `getOnlyBooksOrOnlyRocks(booksAndRocks)`, with no `<Rock>` in there to tell your program which type you want.

The only way this could possibly work is to pass a *value* that specifies the type you want into `getOnlyBooksOrOnlyRocks()`, from which the generic type argument could be inferred by the compiler.

---

For example, if you're willing to pass in a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) such as `isBook` or `isRock`:

```
const isBook = (x: BookOrRock): x is Book => 'pages' in x;
const isRock = (x: BookOrRock): x is Rock => 'shape' in x;
```

like this:

```
const rocks = getOnlyBooksOrOnlyRocks(isRock, booksAndRocks);
```

then you can define `getOnlyBooksOrOnlyRocks` like this:

```
const getOnlyBooksOrOnlyRocks = <T extends BookOrRock>(
    isType: (x: BookOrRock) => x is T,
    array: BookOrRock[]
): T[] => {
    const filtered: T[] = [];
    for (const el of array) {
        if (isType(el)) filtered.push(el);
    }
    return filtered;
};
```

That compiles without error.  You can see that the type of `isType` is `(x: BookOrRock) => x is T`, so hopefully the compiler can infer `T` from the type of the function passed in.

Note that you could implement this more simply as

```
const getOnlyBooksOrOnlyRocks = <T extends BookOrRock>(
    isType: (x: BookOrRock) => x is T,
    array: BookOrRock[]
): T[] => {
    return array.filter(isType); 
};
```

because [one of TypeScript's call signatures for the `filter()` array method](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/354891cf435b475307d2ba4ddbe1dd9ee9db8729/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1434) captures the idea that a type guard callback should narrow the type of the filtered array.

---

Let's make sure that it works:

```
const booksAndRocks: BookOrRock[] = [
    { age: 1, pages: 100 },
    { age: 1e9, shape: 'round' },
];

const rocks = getOnlyBooksOrOnlyRocks(isRock, booksAndRocks);
// const rocks: Rock[]
console.log(rocks.map(r => r.shape.toUpperCase()).join(", ")) // "ROUND"

const books = getOnlyBooksOrOnlyRocks(isBook, booksAndRocks);
// const books: Book[]
console.log(books.map(b => b.pages.toFixed(2)).join(", ")) // "100.00"
```

Looks good!  The compiler infers `Rock` for `T` in the first call because `isRock` has return type `x is Rock`, and it infers `Book` for `T` in the second call has return type `x is Book`.

---

There are other ways to do this, but all of them will involve some actual value argument that can be used to distinguish the "filter `Rock`s" case from the "filter `Book`s" case.  If you want to call `getOnlyBooksOrOnlyRocks("Rock", booksAndRocks)` instead of `getOnlyBooksOrOnlyRocks(isRock, booksAndRocks)`, you could set up a mapping object from strings like `"Rock"` and `"Book"` to the relevant type guard functions.  But I won't belabor the point by detailing how that would be implemented.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHt0GtkG8BQyRycA5hAFzIgCuAtgEbQDchxADmRAM5W2Mt8AX3z5QkWIhQAldAhwFiJcn3pMorJdwAWcdpWTcwUUKVYj8YAJ760mLAHkos+cgC8yABQZsyAGR4hrr6APx8EABu0MhCAJTIAD5eLjgBuMic5Nxh1JHRcaz4COggRsjA3D44Hp4AHlRVTimxVLXl3Ha+bgB8yADkmTx95SDItazFpWDtKe5e9Z2OznJYLWPtyLM9-Tp6EMOgY4WTZeRgDiAANlZV3E4X1ykdHgA8ACrIELWQIAAmHY1lvJup42EQKm8bAY6g17E0VvFtm0Ksg3gAaMEkKBQOBWWHYeHyADaAF18Gs3qT3L1FMQTtMYMBLhIIL8qJSSXNSZpiDB0FAvPTPpdkOgYFicVZ4rSlODxZ4IVDPBBLrF4ozmdBWQA6dg0HTK1U8ogiJRQCBgGhQUYalm-czHEqnC0PG72O5QV1PABMc3en2+ED+ALhQKwIMxiv0VBhi0Jq2p6xR6MxcGxuPxSxSpPJ7Kp2xlyHNlutEtx2tt0AV3Eh+liDtERSd0wY7oAgn8npn4-nkETMekuFQAIxojJcXjIYcABmnMQxSkHKinEAAnGPdtH+lB0DQ-sMhBiSY6pkWVs9kGdXbd7lcrE9qykx63sNwO78nvX8AB6b-IIU7vIk7ZmSJzoJcEDapc6CkJ4gFYNw2p0HocGJlA2qbpBYDoAAquw+hQAAwnA3AQJ4aragAVugoCeAARGOdFqsgv7IHR0gODhAByAAidGiEKL4IXMV53jenp3g+FRVM+7adueX6sYJ7qZjmYEQVBMGeEJiHIew2mJgwuoTtq2EAGLALUrKeN6FHUbRDFscxrF0TO07arOdFAA)